# Unable to dynamically show different content based on adding method using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-deployment

```
/*Add new div(content)*/
<div class="form-group"> 
<button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-sm" id="add-phone">Add</button> 
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var max_fields = 3; //maximum input boxes allowed
var x = 1; //initlal text box count

   $('#add-phone').click(function () {   
       if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
           x++; //increment when a new div(section) is added.
         //content of added section(div)
        $("#add-request").after('<div class="col-md-12" id="site-phone">
        <select name='phone-manufacture' id="phone-manufacture">
       <option value="apple">Apple</option><option value="sam">Samsung</option></select></div>');
    });

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#phone-manufacture').change(
        function () {
          var method = $('option:selected').val();
             if (this.value == 'apple'){
              //show different content(Fields, text or another select)
            }else if(this.value == 'sam'){
              //show something else or append a new element..
            }
      });
    });

</script>
```

This is what I have so far but it only works when adding the first div(pressing the add button once) but when adding a second div(content -Pressing add button for a 2nd time) or third div(content) is not longer showing the different elements specified on the If block.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you please further explain what you like to do?

Comment: I would like to  add a new div every time the add button is pressed. Once the new div shows, it will show a select option where user gets to select either option 1 or 2. Based on selection then textfields will be shown.. I have already accomplished that.. The problem is that when the user click on the add button again.. the dynamic textfields doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new elements that have the same ID. Each element should have a unique ID. You should use a class reference for your change function NOT an ID reference(see example below where I've added a class called phone-manufacture and used that for your change function"). Also, note that I've used `$(document).on` for your change function. This is because when you dynamically add elements, you need to attach the event handler to a non-dynamic element:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
var max_fields = 3; //maximum input boxes allowed
var x = 1; //initlal text box count

$('#add-phone').click(function () {
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //increment when a new div(section) is added.
        //content of added section(div)
        $("#add-request").after('<div class="col-md-12" id="site-phone"><select name="phone-manufacture" id="phone-manufacture" class="phone-manufacture"> <option value="apple">Apple</option><option value="sam">Samsung</option></select></div>');
    }
});



     $(document).on('change','.phone-manufacture', function(){
            var method = $('option:selected').val();
            if (this.value == 'apple'){
                //show different content(Fields, text or another select)
            }else if(this.value == 'sam'){
                //show something else or append a new element..
            }
        });
});

</script>
```

Note: I haven't changed your ids in this, but you should also address that issue.